# reload page on select new value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework

i work on a script that i should get the folder of my gmail adress
i work on zend_framework 
i got the into   :

```
<?php
                    $mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($setting);
                    $folders = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($mail->getFolders(), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                    echo '<select id="dir" class="form-control" name="folder">';
                    foreach ($folders as $localName => $folder) {
                        $localName = str_pad('', $folders->getDepth(), '-', STR_PAD_LEFT) .
                                $localName;
                        echo '<option';
                        if (!$folder->isSelectable()) {
                            echo ' disabled="disabled"';
                        }
                        echo ' value="' . htmlspecialchars($folder) . '" >'
                        . htmlspecialchars($localName) . '</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                    //$mail->selectFolder("Inbox");
                    ?>
```

i did try to reload the page when i change the folder of mail , exemple from inbox to spam or drafts, i did try to use a small javascript function to reload the page but still after the refresh the inbox page , how can i resolve this 
thx

Answer (score 0):

You could post the value of your select box to the page and then pull that data into your php.

So, the javascript would be something like this (this should go in a document ready statement):

```
jQuery('#dir').change(function(){
    var dirVal = jQuery(this).val();
    $.post(window.location, {dir: 'dirVal'});
});
```

And then change your PHP to something like this (note the if statement checking the value against the posted 'dir' value from our JS):

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($setting);
$folders = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($mail->getFolders(), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
echo '<select id="dir" class="form-control" name="folder">';
foreach ($folders as $localName => $folder) {
    $localName = str_pad('', $folders->getDepth(), '-', STR_PAD_LEFT) . $localName;
    echo '<option';
    if (!$folder->isSelectable()) {
        echo ' disabled="disabled"';
    }
    if($_POST['dir'] == htmlspecialchars($folder)){
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo ' value="' . htmlspecialchars($folder) . '" >' . htmlspecialchars($localName) . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

This is untested and may take some modifications, but this is the basic concept. Post the val and then select based on that post val.

Comment: thx for your replay but i got this error Undefined index: dir in <b>/var/www/html/imap/application/views/scripts/main/index.phtml , exact here : if($_POST['dir'] == htmlspecialchars($folder)){

Comment: You will get an undefined index error on the first load as you're not posting the dir variable. Try changing the if statement to :

if(isset($_POST['dir']) && $_POST['dir'] == htmlspecialchars($folder)){
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    }

Comment: hi mikel thanks for your answer , but still cannot be redirect to the folder after selecting it , do you suggest any other solution for this issue

Comment: Hey Jeddey, I'd be happy to help. Could you post a functional jsbin of your page so that I can fix up some code? Jsbin.com is free to use and a great tool for situations like this. Perhaps consider pasting the full updated PHP as well.